# AWS autoscaling - retain Target group instance port

Tags: aws-auto-scaling

I am setting up autoscaling group with Application Load Balancer in AWS. The Load Balancer target group's instance port is set to 8080(where tomcat is running on EC2).  Whenever I do a instance refresh from autoscaling group to update with latest version of launch template configuration, the target group's instance(that is getting created as part of refresh) is picking up the default port 80 instead of 8080.  how do we ensure the instance port doesnot pick up the default one and use port 8080 while autoscaling group is launching a new instance?